# Diagonalizing a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose the matrices $A,B,C,D$ are $M\times M$, $M\times N$, $N\times M$ and $N\times N$, respectively. Then I give you the following block matrix:

$$
G = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Apparently the diagonal form of $G$ is:

$$
R^{-1}GR = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A -BD^{-1}C& 0 \\
0 & D
\end{pmatrix}
$$

for some $R$ but how can I show this?

Comment: How do you know that $D$ is diagonal? Anyway, this does not seem to work for $A=(1)$, $B=(-1)$, $C=(1)$, $D=(-1)$.

Comment: "Apparently..." How is it apparent?

Answer (score 6):

It would be better to refer to what you identified as $R^{-1} GR$ as a *block* diagonal matrix (rather than a diagonal matrix).

Depending on what properties are assumed, you may be able to prove existence via the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).  But not every matrix, even with $D$ invertible is *similar* to a block diagonal matrix in the way you've specified.

For example:  $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $.

Instead you seem to have misunderstood a [block elimination scheme](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs6210-f09/lec11.pdf), which is not a similarity transformation but a computation of the *equivalence* transform $RGS$ being the indicated block diagonal matrix.

$$ \begin{pmatrix} I & -BD^{-1} \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ -D^{-1}C & I \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} A-BD^{-1}C & 0 \\ 0 & D \end{pmatrix}  $$